# Leaflet map not displaying GeoJSON data

Tags: typescript, leaflet, powerbi, geojson

i am trying to render some points on a leaflet map embedded in power Bi web. The data submitted to Leaflet is in GeoJSON format.
When i input this data everything works fine and the point is correctly displayed:

```
var someFeatures = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-75, 34]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Location A"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I then tried to insert my data, which is simply a couple Latitude and Longitude.
Here is the code snippet that i'm running:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var popupContent = "<p>I started out as a GeoJSON " +
            feature.geometry.type + ", but now I'm a Leaflet vector!</p>";

        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
          popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
        }

        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
      }


      var dat = Visual.converter(options.dataViews[0].table.rows); //just converts the data to lat lon format

      var test = GeoJSON.parse(dat, {Point: ['lat', 'lon']}) 
        L.geoJSON([test], {
        style: function(feature) {
          return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
        },
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
          });
        }
      }).addTo(this.map);
```

I'm pretty sure the data is converted in a correct format, as shown by the developer console:

[image: Developer console screenshot]

Any help is super appreciated, as i cannot figure out how to solve this issue.

EDIT: The browser console output is the content of the variable "test" getting filled with the output of : GeoJSON.parse(dat, {Point: ['lat', 'lon']}) Where "dat" is the raw data that contains latitude and longitude.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You show a console output, but not the code that generates this output… for instance, do you log `dat` or `test`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the insight, i just forgot that info... The browser console output is the content of the variable "test" getting filled with the output of :

GeoJSON.parse(dat, {Point: ['lat', 'lon']}) 

Where "dat" is the raw data that contains latitude and longitude

Comment: You can _edit_ your question to make it clear right in your question body.